# Monitor iOS internet activity

Tags: ios, browser, vpn, ota

Is there any method to check the iOS device internet activity (safari, whatsapp... etc) OTA ( [Over The Air](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_programming) ) ? I know that iOS cannot monitor safari activity because the apps are run in sandbox.

I think VPN is one of the solution but the log of VPN is not easy to read and there will be a logo on the status bar which the users will know.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Reachability for internet checking

here is links it may helps you.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

You may also refer this Github project

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

feel free to accept my answer

Comment: Thx sp309. But this seems like not suitable for me. Suppose I am boss(A) and i want to monitor my staff (B) surf what website by using his device.

Comment: i.e. A monitor B's phone
and the result that i want is something like
14/10/15 B www.stackoverflow.com

Is there any other method?